# Need to make Image Bottom to corner: React Native

Tags: android, ios, image, react-native, rounded-corners

I want to make image rounded from bottom of it. Here is what I wanted to make:
[image]

I have tried to set **borderRadius**, but it will apply for the whole image not for bottom.

Here is my code:

```
<View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: ‘transparent’,
          justifyContent: ‘center’,
          alignItems: ‘center’,
          height: 159,
          width: '100%',
          borderBottomWidth: 70,
          borderBottomColor: ‘red’,
          borderBottomRightRadius: 800,
          borderBottomLeftRadius: 800,
        }}
      />
```

It will give output like this:

[image]

Which property do I need to set to make a perfect round on the bottom of view?

Comment: Radii are applied to corners not edges

Comment: @Wainage Didn't get you.

Answer (score 3):

<del>you can add a png frame transparent with this shape on it</del>

also you can check this it may help [the-shapes-of-react-native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peB5y.png)

---

**Update**

here is how I managed do this by code

first you create this structure

```
render() {
  return(
    <View style={styles.container} >
      <View style={styles.background} >
        <Image style={styles.image} source={require('./image.jpeg')} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

and then apply this style

```
const styles = {
  container: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: 100,
    width: 200,
    overflow: 'hidden', // for hide the not important parts from circle
    margin: 10,
    height: 100,
  },
  background: { // this shape is a circle 
    borderRadius: 400, // border borderRadius same as width and height
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    marginLeft: -100, // reposition the circle inside parent view
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0, // show the bottom part of circle
    overflow: 'hidden', // hide not important part of image
  },
  image: {
    height: 100, // same width and height for the container
    width: 200,
    position: 'absolute', // position it in circle
    bottom: 0, // position it in circle
    marginLeft: 100, // center it in main view same value as marginLeft for circle but positive
  }
}
```

and here is the results

[image: round shape image for react native]

Comment: I already go through with your link. But didn't get any idea how to do it.

Comment: what about making a transparent png with this shape & make it with absolute position above the image

Comment: I keep it for last option. If we get perfect ans then it will help in future

Answer (score 2):

Using the approach mentioned by [@Mohamed Khalil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7149898/mohamed-khalil),

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
containerStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: window.width,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    height: window.width / 1.7
},
sliderContainerStyle: {
    borderRadius: window.width,
    width: window.width * 2,
    height: window.width * 2,
    marginLeft: -(window.width / 2),
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    overflow: 'hidden'
},
slider: {
    height: window.width / 1.7,
    width: window.width,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    marginLeft: window.width / 2,
    backgroundColor: '#9DD6EB'
}});
```

Here is the result. I used `Dimensions` (`const window = Dimensions.get('window');`) here to make it more dynamic to different screen sizes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check my repository, if it helps you

https://github.com/paraswatts/React_Native_Custom_shape_image_view/tree/master

There is a catch I have squeezed the width of image and then scaled it on X-axis