# Curved bottom on View

Tags: react-native

How can i add the curved bottom to a View in react-native? [See curved example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9d6j.png)

I'f tried to a add an second view like this:

headerBottom: {
    width: width / 2,
    height: width / 2,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: -35,
    left: width / 4 - 15,
    borderRadius: width / 4,
    transform: [
      {scaleX: 2},
      {scaleY: 0.25}
    ]
  },

I've been able to get above but rather have a less bad solution right in the same view, not as in the example in a second view.

Comment: Not an answer but for future readers, this is a very similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220316/need-to-make-image-bottom-to-corner-react-native) about `Image` components.

Comment: check my answer on this thread, if it helps you,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220316/need-to-make-image-bottom-to-corner-react-native/46245870#46245870

Comment: Thank you for your ideas! I have reviewed your proposals and will implement it soon. I was hoping for a more beautiful solution through borderBottomRadius or something, but that is not possible yet.

Thanks anyway

Comment: Did you get any solution for this @MvdL?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up with using `react-native-svg`.:

```
<Circle
  cx={screenWidth / 2}
  cy={`-${898 - headerHeight + 2}`}
  r="898.5"
  fill="#EFF2F3"
  stroke="#C5CACD"
  strokeWidth="2"
/>
```

Answer (score 21):

Here is the result. I used Dimensions (const window = Dimensions.get('window');) here to make it more dynamic to different screen sizes.

[image]

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
containerStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: window.width,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    height: window.width / 1.7
},
sliderContainerStyle: {
    borderRadius: window.width,
    width: window.width * 2,
    height: window.width * 2,
    marginLeft: -(window.width / 2),
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    overflow: 'hidden'
},
slider: {
    height: window.width / 1.7,
    width: window.width,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    marginLeft: window.width / 2,
    backgroundColor: '#9DD6EB'
}});


render() {
  return(
    <View style={styles.containerStyle} >
      <View style={styles.sliderContainerStyle} >
        <Slider/>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I don't know whether this is a proper way or not. However this works for me and hope this will help someone.

```
<View style={styles.parent}>
     <View style={styles.child}>
         <Text>Hello World</Text>
     </View>
</View>
```

Insert your code to child View

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    parent : {
        height : '80%',
        width : '100%',
        transform : [ { scaleX : 2 } ],
        borderBottomStartRadius : 200,
        borderBottomEndRadius : 200,
        overflow : 'hidden',
    },
    child : {
        flex : 1,
        transform : [ { scaleX : 0.5 } ],

        backgroundColor : 'yellow',
        alignItems : 'center',
        justifyContent : 'center'
    }
})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, This answer was the savior for me, pretty good hack.

Comment: Not worked for me. not showing any curve

Comment: This is a awesome...!