# React Native - create curved edge for shape

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

**Summary of problem**

I have the following bottom navigation bar for an app I'm building and I'm not sure how to style it since it's more complex than anything I've styled in the past.  I'm having trouble styling the curved top edge of the white part and the area between the blue/green circle and the white part.

I included what the navigation bar should look like from the mockups since one of them seems to blend in.  The black background above the white part between the green/blue circle and the white part shouldn't be styled with this Navigation bar, that should be the background seen behind the navigation bar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Navigation Bar Example]
**Summary Code**

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
  </View>

container: {
    width: windowWidth,
    height: windowHeight * 0.1020935961,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    borderTopLeftRadius: -50,
    borderTopRightRadius: -50
  }
```

**Full Code**

```
const CustomTabNav = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.instant}
      onPress={() => {
        NavigationService.navigate("Home");
      }}
    >
      <Image
        style={styles.homeImage}
        source={require("~/assets/images/homeIcon.png")}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.ovalCopy}
      onPress={() => NavigationService.navigate("Competitions")}
    >
      <LinearGradient
        start={{ x: 0, y: 1 }}
        end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
        colors={[buttonGradientBlueColor, buttonGradientGreenColor]}
        style={styles.linearGradient}
      >
        <Image
          style={styles.plusImage}
          source={require("~/assets/images/plus.png")}
        />
      </LinearGradient>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.instant}
      onPress={() => NavigationService.navigate("Competitions")}
    >
      <Image
        style={styles.instantImage}
        source={require("~/assets/images/competitions.png")}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: windowWidth,
    height: windowHeight * 0.1020935961,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    borderTopLeftRadius: -50,
    borderTopRightRadius: -50
  },
  homeImage: {
    width: windowWidth * 0.05,
    height: windowWidth * 0.05
  },
  instant: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    // alignSelf: 'center',
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  instantImage: {
    width: windowWidth * 0.05,
    height: windowWidth * 0.05
  },
  ovalCopy: {
    width: 64,
    height: 64,
  },
  linearGradient: {
    borderRadius: 50, //TODO: make sure this is correct
    width: 64,
    height: 64,
    shadowColor: "#0a0b12cc",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: -10
    },
    shadowRadius: 60,
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  plusImage: {
    width: windowWidth*0.064,
    height: windowWidth*0.064
  }
});
```

Comment: please share your code width us

Comment: I just updated the question with my code, thanks for the suggestion @XenioGracias !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curved bottom on View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244995/curved-bottom-on-view)

Comment: can you please add a working link of it?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I guess you could do it in a hard way like making a background picture for getting that curvy white background.
Or you could superpose 2 "black-grey" views on top of a white view. The first "black-grey" could be one like with a incredible big borderRadius, and second one a 100% circle one slightly bigger than the + button.
This is what I mean:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor:"white",height: HEIGHT ,width:WIDTH, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'flex-start' }}>
            <View style={{ backgroundColor:"black",borderBottomLeftRadius:WIDTH*10,borderBottomRightRadius:WIDTH*10,height: HEIGHT*.6 ,width:WIDTH*2, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
</View>
            <View style={{ backgroundColor:"black",borderRadius:60,height: 120 ,width:120, marginTop:-60,alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <View style={{ backgroundColor:"white",borderRadius:40,height: 80 ,width:80 ,alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    <Icon name="chevron-left" size={30} />
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{ backgroundColor:"transparent",height: 120 ,width:WIDTH, marginTop:-60,flexDirection:"row",padding:20, justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                <Icon name="chevron-left" size={30} />
                <Icon name="chevron-left" size={30} />
            </View>
    </View>
```

Screenshoot of what you will get: [Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXlj9.png)